# I wanna adjust submit button and text same level

Tags: button, submit

The following is my code and I have been trying to make the text fields and submit button to the same level. I do not have a style script with it though:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>

<form action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;">

<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1557121664" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />

<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="perfumestore" />

<input id="redirect_55278f131e8a7214d84411f07f48b533" type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou.htm?m=default" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="Frontpage" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />

</div>
<div align="right">
<input id="awf_field-61288568" tabindex="500" type="text" name="email" value="" onFocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onBlur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

<div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add inline styles for the div as well as input.

- add align="left" or align="right"
- you can use Float, padding also.

hope this helps